# Add aspx in url to umbraco pages

Tags: umbraco

I'm using Umbraco 7.15 version, i would like to keep .aspx ending in the url. is it possible to do so? the umbraco is blocking me in the page itself.

Comment: Is there any specific reason you would like to keep the URL's ending in .aspx? .ASPX is the file format for ASP.NET WebForms page files and Umbraco 7 is running ASP.NET MVC, so to me, it doesn't really seem to make sense to want to add .ASPX to the URLs.

Comment: I dont want the SEO traffic will be in decrease in the short range for now. Im sure in the long term that we will terminate the .aspx.

Answer (score 1):

Update: found 2 solutions to the problem

```
<rewrite>
     <rewriteMaps configSource="rewritemaps.config" />     
      <rules>
            <rule name="Redirect rule1 for Redirects">
              <match url=".*" />
              <conditions>
              <add input="{Redirects:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

and changing the umbracoUseDirectoryUrls in the web.config to false.
anyone know the consequences of this solutions?